# How can I calculate the 2 datetime picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 datetimepickers and I want to know to calculate the day or time.

Ex:

> 2017-01-12 09:00:00
>   2017-01-12 10:00:00

The answer should be 1:00:00

Below is my code. I also wanna know the date time formatting for this.

```
<input required type="text" class="form-control" id="time_in">
<input required type="text" class="form-control" id="time_out">
```

```
$start_time = $("#time_in").val();
$end_time = $("#time_out").val();

$answer = date_diff($start_time, $end_time)
alert($start_time);
```

Comment: you probably want alert($answer);

Comment: Why are you using text inputs instead of date pickers ?

Comment: Also what is `date_diff()`?

Comment: the inputs are datetime pickers sir.

Comment: the date_diff is not working i just tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want to achieve.
Try:

```js
old_date = "2010-11-10 07:00:00";
new_date = "2010-11-10 08:00:00";
old_date_obj = new Date(Date.parse(old_date, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
new_date_obj = new Date(Date.parse(new_date, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
t = (new_date_obj - old_date_obj);
seconds=(t/1000)%60
minutes=(t/(1000*60))%60
hours=(t/(1000*60*60))%24
alert(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

probably want something like

```
function date_diff(start, end)
{
    var d1 = new Date(start);
    var d2 = new Date(end);
    return d2-d1;
}
```

note that the answer here is in miliseconds

Comment: is this java script sir?

Comment: yep (no jquery, just pure js)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date;
date = new Date("$start_time);
var startTime = date.getTime(); 
date = new Date("$end_time); 
var endTime = date.getTime();
var difference=startTime-endTime;
var answer= new Date(difference);
```

Hope this Helps.